# Logarithms and exponents with variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain to me in a little more detail how they get to the answer of 6? The properties used and all the stuff they pull out of thin air would be nice or if there is a way to do it in an easier way would be greatly appreciated.

[image: the problem]

If the image doesn't work, the problem is:

$\log_x(\log_{3x}(\log_{6x}(2^{12} 3^{12} 4^6 8^4 9^6 27^4))) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$log_a(b) = c$

This statement means $a^c = b$

This problem can be understood easily if you understand logarithms.

1. $log_x(a) = 0$ implies that $a = 1$ because $x^0 = 1$
2. $log_x(a) = 1$ implies that $a = x$ because $x^1 = x = a$

These two implications are used to solve the problem.

---

$log_x(log_{3x}(log_{6x}(2^{12}3^{12}4^68^49^627^4))) = 0$

By simplification, we get

$log_x(log_{3x}(log_{6x}(6^{36}))) = 0$

Using 1, we get

$log_{3x}(log_{6x}(6^{36})) = 1$

Using 2, we get

$log_{6x}(6^{36}) = 3x$

$(6x)^{3x} = 6^{36}$

By solving, we get $x = 6$

Comment: How do you simplify (6x)^3x=6^36? Also how do you make the numbers exponents and logs and stuff without the ^

Comment: Try all possible values of x in the equation. The math to solve that equation is very complicated.

Comment: Check these out.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13620/how-to-type-math-symbols-in-this-forum

Answer (score 1):

The first few steps are the basic properties of logs. In the end, I think it's easier to go this way: $6^{36}=(6x)^{3x} \implies 6^{12}=(6x)^{x} \implies 1< x=6^y \le 12 \implies y=1, x=6$

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:
$$\log_a(b) = c$$
then you can get rid of the log by raising the log base to the power of each side like this:
$$a^{\log_a(b)} = a^c\\b = a^c$$
This works because that is the definition of $\log_a(b)$ - it is the value such that $a$ raised to that value gives $b$.

If you apply this method three times to get rid of the three logs you end up with $6^{36}=(6x)^{3x}$, to which a simple integer solution can be found by inspection. Note that this is kind of equation with x in the base and in the exponent is not so easily solved in general.

Comment: Do you happen to know what steps you would need to take to simplify the last part? It's ok if you don't I'm just wondering

Comment: @CoolDoodShooz1 If you assume x is an integer, then it must be a power of 6, and as Vasya shows it can then only be $6^1=6$ as any other power gives something far too large. It can be shown that the answer must be unique (since $(6x)^{3x}$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$), so $x=6$ is the only solution. This kind of equation cannot really be simplified further so if you can't guess an exact solution then the best you can do is probably to use numerical methods to get an approximation to the solution.